# Struts1:struts-taglib.jar is not being found by my webapp

Tags: java, jsp, struts, jboss5.x

I am using Struts-1. I have developed a struts-based web application. I am using struts tags in my JSP pages supplied in struts-taglib.jar by inserting the following lines in the JSP file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="html" uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="logic" uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="bean" uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean"%>
```

Now the application is working fine when I run it on my localsystem on JBOSS5 but when I deploy it on a server (also on JBOSS5), it shows the following exception:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://struts.apache.org/tags-html cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
From the above exception, it seems that the application hasn't found the struts-taglib.jar file.

But I have put the struts-taglib.jar in /WEB-INF/lib directory. Then where is the problem?

Comment: What are your local application server and on your deployed application server? Maybe the struts-taglib.jar library is not provided on the deployed server or you already copy it only on local. Do you deploy on local and on the server in the same way?

Comment: Yes deployment is same for local and on the server. I use Jboss 5..

Comment: What version of Struts 1?